# Chilli plant not bearing fruits

Tags: chili, pollination

My Chilli ( type, unknown) plant has 30+ flowers but no fruits. It has couple more symptoms which might be related. Would appreciate any help solving this.

It is outdoor. I do see insects hopping flowers quite regularly. It is in hot sun (35 degree centigrade), I water it daily and it is growing in potting mix and add plant meal or vermi-compost once a month.

1. Lot of lower level leaves have some insect eggs on it on the lower side [image]
2. There are lot of leaves but many small leaves are curled up and facing upwards [image]
3. Flowers dry off and fall without pollinating

Comment: Welcome! Just double-checking: Is the plant outdoors, where pollinating insects have access?

Comment: leaves do not seems good. I think it is physiological (or heavy attack). Could you tell us how do you care your plants? (sun, water, fertilizers)

Comment: I'll also add that some peppers need a bit of pollination help. For example, I find that for whatever reason, Rocoto peppers do not set fruit early in the season unless I hand pollinate with a watercolor brush. After some period of time, things seem to work out without my intervention. I've never figured out if it is because after so much time there are enough flowers or sufficient pollinators or what. But it is a fairly reliable phenomenon in my my experience. And I'd second what @Giacomo said that the leaves look atypical.

Comment: @Novice Gardener More information is needed please provide your: USDA zone, caring regime, age of the plant and specifically, how hot does it get in your region at night?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have powdery mildew AND aphid damage.

You must treat the plants with an authorised insecticide and fungicides for these problems to help the plant recover. 
YOU MUST make sure they are both for food crops. Check with your local garden centre.

For fruits, you need pollination. Identify female and male flowers. Buy a small paint brush and collect pollen from males and place on the female flowers.

You also need to feed your plant with a mix of potassium and phosphorus to make plant stronger. Available from your garden centre.

Please follow all instructions on pesticides, fungicides and macro nutrients uses to avoid health issues

Comment: Good answer, except that all capsicum species have bisexual flowers, so it's not necessary to identify male and female flowers.

Comment: Good point! I forgot!